# How do I get rid of this window in Atom/Typescript?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

How do I get rid of this window in Atom when working with Typescript? What is that window called?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What is that window called

You can call it the `main panel view for TypeScript`.

> How do I get rid of this window?

There isn't an official way (and I don't recommend it). But you can put the following in *your atom styles.less* file to hide it:

```
.atomts-main-panel-view{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Note: this class name will work starting from `v5.0.17` which I just pushed.